# Switch selected value for multiple filtered values in a filter

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

```
Revenue = SWITCH (
      TRUE (),
      SELECTEDVALUE ( 'product_type'[type] ) = "sys", SUM ( table_name[sys_revenue] ),
      SELECTEDVALUE ( 'product_type'[type] ) = "ena", SUM ( table_name[ena_revenue] ),
      SELECTEDVALUE ( 'product_type'[type] ) = "svcs", SUM ( table_name[svcs_revenue] ),
      SELECTEDVALUE('product_type'[type]) ="sys" && SELECTEDVALUE('product_type'[type]) ="disp", SUM ( table_name[sys_displ_revenue] ),
      SELECTEDVALUE ( 'product_type'[type] ) = "", SUM ( table_name[revenue] )
)
```

This measure works perfectly when the selected value is only one but the criteria that I have written with && for multiple selection of the filter product type doesn't work. It gives me the value of SUM (table name[revenue]) for any kind of multiselect on the product type. My task is it only give the values for multiselect of sys & disp and for any other combination of multiselect it should show "blank". Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the VALUES() function instead, it returns an array of values from a column, if that column is being filtered by a slicer then it returns only the selected values.

Edit : Will update the code for VALUES() after I figure out the syntax issue highlighted in comments. Meanwhile CONCATENATEX is an apt work around that can solve the issue mentioned in OP's question.

```
SWITCH(.....
     CONCATENATEX('product_type',[type],",",'product_type'[type]) = "disp,sys", SUM(table_name[sys_displ_revenue]),
    ....)
```

[image]

Comment: Error: Too many arguments were passed to the VALUES function. The maximum argument count for the function is 1.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the code. Please try the updated one on my Answer and let me know if it worked...

Comment: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected is the error.

Comment: can you replace '=' with IN operator

Comment: Sorry, same error

Comment: SWITCH(.....
     CONCATENATEX('product_type',[type],",",'product_type'[type]) = "disp,sys", SUM(table_name[sys_displ_revenue]),
    ....)

pls refer original answer for screenshot

Comment: please try this... I have done this with the VALUES function in the past but can't recall properly. Meanwhile, this should help with the problem you are facing.

Comment: Hey thanks this worked for the combination of sys,disp.